# How to iterate over weeks between two dates in Groovy?

Tags: date, groovy

I am trying to iterate over dates from start to end every week. Currently, I am writing the following code.

```
def current=startDate
    while (current <= endDate) {
        log.debug "Week: ${current}"
        current=current+7
    }
```

Is there a groovier way?

Comment: That seems like pretty clean code (maybe move the 7 into a final variable and statically type `current`).  Is there something in particular you are looking for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering you have two dates `startDate` and `endDate`, this should do the job:

```
(startDate..endDate).step(7) { println it }
```

groovier, isn't it?

Comment: Well executed square drive. ;)